# html href to a https. but it doesn't work

Tags: html, https, href

i'm user  to link to a https website. like this:

```
<a href="https://site/#create/new/?">
```

but when i click on the link, it cannot direct to the correct page, instead, it direct to `https://site/#create%2fnew%2f%3f`
How to fix this? anyone could help?

Thanks

Comment: This is [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) at work. It does what it's supposed to do. You didn't say which language you're using at serverside, so we can't tell you how to decode it.

Comment: hi @Amadan i'm just using html. i just want to put the simple link to that website,thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's not the correct page? pure HTML pages are not aware of URLs.

Comment: @Amadan it's not correct, because it is not the page i want to go

Comment: It is the same page. Everything after `#` is only regarded by browsers; the page in both cases is `https://site/`. Which brings me back to my point: what makes you think it's incorrect? Who is reporting it? Are you looking in the server logs? Browser debugger? Are you getting it from the target page's JavaScript? The other site's PHP script? What is the reason that makes you think it's not the right page?

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the explanation. That's an external url. if i put https://site/#create/new/? directly in the browser, it will direct me to a page that has a form waiting me fill in. but if i put that link in href (i have my own site , i want to use the link to direct me to that external site), it will direct me to that page, but only shows left handside navigation bar, no form appears. is this clear?

Comment: It appears that it is problematic JavaScript on the target page. They would need to run `decodeURIComponent` on the URL, but they don't. I don't think there is anything you can do except bug them to fix it. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What Adaman is saying is that #create... is a fragment identifier for the page `/site/index.[html|htm|php]`. Are you sure the URL is correct? Should it be something like the following: `https://example.com/create/new/`?